# Rolling 1 die 5 times

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

One die is rolled five times. How many different results are possible? Of those, in how many ways can there be exactly 2 rolls of 4?

For the first part I multiplied 6 five times and got 7776. I'm stuck on the second part "...in how many ways can there be exactly 2 rolls of 4?"

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include any work you have done and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: What counts as "different"?  Is, for example, $1, 1, 2, 1, 2$ different from $2, 2, 1, 1, 1$, or is it counted as the same?

Comment: This is my first time posting on this site, so I apologize for not posting according to guidelines. For the first part of the question "How many different results are possible" I multiplied 6 five times and got 7776. I'm stuck on the second part "Of those, in how many ways can there be exactly 2 rolls of 4?" Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Different results possible=choices with first roll $*$ second roll $*..*$ fifth roll

$$
=6*6*6*6*6
$$
$$
=6^5
$$

For the second case,
$$
=\binom{5}{2}*1*1*5*5*5
$$
$$
=\binom{5}{2}*5^3
$$

Think of it as, there are $5$ boxes and you need to fill numbers from $1-6$ in them such that exactly $2$ boxes contain $4$.

$\binom{5}{2}*1*1$ chooses the number of possible ways for boxes for which exactly $2$ boxes contain $4$ . Now there are $3$ boxes left so you can place either $1,2,3,5,6$ so there are $5$ for $3$ boxes therefore ,$5^3$.

So , answer=$$\binom{5}{2}*5^3$$

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand how you got 1*1*5*5*5. Can you please explain? Thank you.